# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation Fault Tolerance

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fault-tolerance

Assuming a completely reliable SQL Server infrastructure (i.e. SQL Server is not part of the question), what is the simplest and cheapest (i.e. minimum number of servers) method of making a fault-tolerant SharePoint 2010 Foundation installation? The goal is that if a server fails for any reason, the SharePoint infrastructure would not be compromised. So, I'm looking for server-level hardware fault tolerance.

Would it just be a matter of installing two identical servers and then somehow load-balancing the access to them? I'd like advice from a SharePoint guru on how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Read these two articles and let me know if you have more questions:

- [Plan for redundancy (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263044(office.12).aspx)
- [Plan for availability (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748824.aspx)

I also recommend [*MOSS 2007 Administrator's Companion*](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/9537.aspx) by Bill English - it contains chapters on configuring network load balancing and implementing fault tolerance.

Comment: Actually that 2010 document is really helpful and not too verbose. Thanks for the link. +1